# Sonata Media Bundle : How to set the default value of a media field?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-sonata

I'm currently Sonata Media Bundle for my project.
In one of my Entity Form Type that has some Media fields, I added these fields :

```
<?php
$builder
    ->add('image', 'sonata_media_type', array(
        'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
        'context' => 'projects',
        'label' => 'Project image',
        'required' => true

    ))
    ->add('video', 'sonata_media_type', array(
        'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.vimeo',
        'context' => 'projects',
        'label' => 'Vimeo video',
        'required' => true
    ));
?>
```

As you can see, my two fields are required. However, when I add a media and save the entity, and then when I want to edit it, I don't have the related media as the "default" value as it should be set, generating my HTML5 required warning when trying to saving my edited entity with no new values in my media fields.

- Is it the expected behavior? I tried to use a workaround with a PRE_SET_DATA FormEvent that would set the media fields as unrequired when there is existing data, but I don't think it's a good way to handle this
- How to set the existing value of the media fields in entity edit forms?

Thank you for your help.